# Best integer solution to overdetermined linear system with full column rank

Tags: systems-of-equations, least-squares

I have this impossible system and would like to have an aproximate solution through the least square method, but i'm having some problems figuring what to do, so i followed some guide on my book and got a solution, but i don't fully trust what i got.

$$2N+M=8$$
$$N+M=6$$
$$3N+M=5$$
$$N+3M=12$$
ps: I'm lacking skills to make this look like a system, but it is a system of 4 equations.

N and M are restricted to being integers

Well, i got $$N=128/33$$ and $$M=279/297$$ but it seems kind off.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get it.  The system is certainly (very) inconsistent.  What's the point of the question?

Comment: @randall the point is to find the approximate solution that minimizes the square error. The exact same thing we do when we plot a regression line (which is an approximate solution to an inconsistent system of equations.)

Comment: (To op) although you probably should have shown your work so we could diagnose your mistake if you were wrong, in this case my matlab prompt agrees with your answer so I guess you did it right.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yeah, i didn't do that because of my struggle to input a linear system of equations, imagine a whole solution. Do you have the code for matlab? I do have one also but didn't know how to use, so i did by hand. Mine has two inputs (x and y) and one generator function but i didn't write the algorithm so couldn't manage to make it work

Comment: Well doing it by hand is good for the character I suppose but I wouldn't have checked it for you if matlab weren't open on my desktop right now. (Actually on closer examination I think you got N and M switched.) The code was: X=[2 1; 1 1; 3 1; 1 3]; y = [8; 6; 5; 12]; b = X \ y

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen what would that b be?

Comment: b will be the column vector $[\hat N; \hat M]$ of the least squares estimates of $N$ and $M.$ The '\' operation may be unfamiliar: see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html .

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks fam

Answer (score 0):

### Problem statement

Find the least squares solutions for the following linear system
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbf{A} & x & = & b \\
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    3 & 1 \\
    \tfrac{1}{3} & 4
    \end{bmatrix}
&
    \begin{bmatrix}
    N \\ M
    \end{bmatrix}
&=&
    \begin{bmatrix}
    8 \\
    6 \\
    5 \\
    4
    \end{bmatrix}
&
\end{array}
$$
The system has $m=4$ rows, $n=2$ columns. The columns are linearly independent, therefore the matrix rank $\rho=2$.

Conclusions: This is an overdetermined system $(m>n)$ with full column rank $(\rho=n)$. The solution will be unique.

### Solution

For the overdetermined problem, form the new linear system by premultiplying both sides of the original system by the adjoint matrix $\mathbf{A}^{*}$.

#### Normal equations

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\phantom{\tfrac{1}{9}}\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} & x & = &  
\phantom{\tfrac{1}{3}}\mathbf{A}^{*} b\\    
    \tfrac{1}{9}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    127 & 57 \\
    57 & 36
    \end{bmatrix}
&
    \begin{bmatrix}
    N \\ M
    \end{bmatrix}
& =
&
    \tfrac{1}{3}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    115 \\
    69
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{array}$$

#### Least squares solution

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
x_{LS} & = 
& \phantom{\tfrac{1}{147}}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} 
& \phantom{\tfrac{1}{3}}\mathbf{A}^{*}b \\
\begin{bmatrix}
    N \\ M
    \end{bmatrix}
& = & \tfrac{1}{147} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    36 & -57 \\
    -57 & 127
    \end{bmatrix}
&   \tfrac{1}{3}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    115 \\
    69
    \end{bmatrix}
& =
&   \tfrac{1}{147}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    69 \\
    736
    \end{bmatrix}
& \approx
&   \begin{bmatrix}
    0.469388 \\
    5.0068
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{array}$$

#### Error

The minimum error for this problem is
$$
\lVert \mathbf{A}x_{LS}-b \rVert_{2}^{2} = 
\frac{1154}{147}
\approx 7.85034
$$
The uncertainty in the fit parameters is
$$\sigma^{2}=\frac
{\lVert \mathbf{A}x_{LS}-b \rVert_{2}^{2}}
{m-n}
\text{diagonal }
\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} 
= \tfrac{1}{21\,609}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    20\,772 \\
    73\,279
    \end{bmatrix}
\approx 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0.961266 \\
    3.39113
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
The final answer observes significant digits and is
$$
\boxed{
x_{LS} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0.46 \\
    5.0
    \end{bmatrix}
\pm
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0.98 \\
    1.8
    \end{bmatrix}}
$$

### Visualizations

#### Merit function

The merit function minimized by the least squares process is
$$
\chi^{2}\left( N, M\right)=
\Bigg\Vert
\mathbf{A}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    N \\
    M
    \end{bmatrix}
- b
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2},
$$
and is plotted below. The gray, elliptical lines are level sets. The blue circles are 1, 2, and, 3 $\sigma$ curves.

[image: merit function]

#### Data vector

The graph below offers the perspective of signal to noise. The data vector $b$ is resolved into $\color{blue}{range}$ (signal) and $\color{red}{null}$ space (noise) components. The vector formula is
$$
b = \color{blue}{b_{R(A)}} + \color{red}{b_{N(A^{*})}}
$$

[image: data vector]

The Pythagorean equality is 
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
b^{2} &= &\color{blue}{b_{R(A)}^{2}} &+ &\color{red}{b_{N(A^{*})}^{2}}\\
141^{2} &= & 133.15^{2} & + & 7.85^{2}
\end{array}
$$

### Integer solution

For convenience, a set of points marking integer locations is superimposed on the merit function. This provides a feel for how quickly the merit function changes as $N$ and $M$ experience unit changes.

[image: merit function with measles]

The results are
$$
    \begin{array}{c}
 N & M & \chi^{2}\left( N, M \right) \\\hline
 0 & 4 & 21 \\
 0 & 5 & 11 \\
 0 & 6 & 9 \\
 1 & 4 & 9.11111 \\
 1 & 5 & 11.7778 \\
 1 & 6 & 22.4444 \\
    \end{array}
$$

The best integer answer is $(0,6)$ where the error is
$$
\chi^{2}\left( 0, 6\right)= 9.
$$